# Labels not aligned in pageblocksection in visualforce

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have visual force page where the code for that is something similar to this.

```
<apex:page standardController="Order__c" extensions="PadController" tabStyle="Account">
<apex:detail />
    <apex:form > 
        <apex:pageBlock >
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!reset}" value="Edit"/>               
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" title="Sample pad" rendered="{!rend}">               
                <apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.Ordered_By__c}"/>  
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem ></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>                   
                <apex:inputField value="{!Order__c.Areas__c}"/>                
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem ></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                <apex:selectList value="{!samplepro}" size="1">
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="out"/>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
                        <b style="font: bold 11.25px Arial;color:#504A4B ;">Sample Pro</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!samplepros}">                     
                        </apex:selectOptions>    
                </apex:selectList>                 
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageblocksection rendered="{!rendsave}">            
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Order__c.Ordered_By__c}"/>
                        <apex:pageBlockSectionItem ></apex:pageBlockSectionItem>                  
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Order__c.Areas__c}"/>
                        <apex:outputPanel id="out">
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;                   
                        <b style="font: bold 11.25px Arial;color:#504A4B ;">Sample Pro</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <apex:outputText value="{!samplepro}">
                    </apex:outputText>
                </apex:outputPanel>                                   
            </apex:pageBlockSection>

        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>    
</apex:page>
```

the samplepro label doesnt properly align with the rest of the fileds. Even the font is not properly matched. Same the case in both the pages.
I am new to this. Please explain me how to align all the fields along with the font family.
I have given css styling just to match it with rest of the fields but even then it not proper.
Please help me out .

Comment: No, it may help if you include on in your question :).  Though I do believe some mis-alignments are how SF has build it, and hasn't been fixed or is considered not important. If it's not a lot, ask yourself how much time this is worth.